# AppleScript to Get Open TextEdit RTF or RTFD File Properties & Copy to Clipboard?

Tags: properties, applescript, clipboard, document, textedit

If you change TextEdit's format to RTD or RTFD you can store various file properties.

These are accessed by opening a small popup window by choosing "File > Show Properties" in the Finder Menu.

[Show Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUWLe.png)

If there anyway to get these values from a current open TextEdit document via Applescript and copy them to the clipboard?

I have not been able to find how to reference these properties in code.